# Dialog Overlay is not working

Tags: jquery, dialog, overlay

Please tell me why this overlay is not working. I'm planning to pop up a div when the user press at the hlFeedback link.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#hlfeedback').click(function () {
            var dlg = jQuery('div#message').dialog({
                width: 608,
                height: 750,
                modal: true,
                overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 },
                buttons: {},
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                }
            });
            dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The div#message is working properly but the only thing is not working is the overlay part. I want to have a black background with opacity 0.5. What is the wrong?!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI dialog doesn't have an `overlay` option, but you can change it pretty easily with CSS:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
   background-color: #000;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: even if i am using css2 and IE 8.0 ?!

Comment: @7alhashmi `opacity` doesn't work in IE8 but you can use `filter: alpha(opacity=50);`

Comment: i tried these four and i didnt get anything. background-color: #000;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   opacity: 0.5;
   filter: alpha(opacity=50);

Comment: Try `-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";`

Comment: @7alhashmi then I don't know; google IE8 opacity and figure it out

Comment: are you sure about .ui-widget-overlay thingy??